# Java OCR: Reading cursive handwriting

Tags: java, ocr

I'm trying to develop and algorithm to read cursive handwriting (doctors' handwriting to be exact). I don't need to match every single letter, just the recognizable ones (I'm using dictionary approach).

For now, I have the binarized image in `BufferedImage` class. What I need to do next is to isolate each character.

Can you provide me of a pseudocode on how can I achieve this? I would like to be minimal in using other libraries. I want to do this by learning how each process is achieved. Any hints?

Comment: I thought doctors' handwriting was by definition illegible - even for humans...

Comment: @thkala well, some characters are readable. Having a dictionary of drug names, this algo can help identify what particular drug is on the prescription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to learn about stuff such as [Image Moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment)  that can be used to compare images even if they have been rotated or scaled

You would need heavy math background to understand how to do that, you can start by reading this http://www.ias.ac.in/sadhana/Pdf2007Oct/521 , it is about how an OCR for a particular kind of characters (Kannada) was implemented, the same general principles should apply for what you are trying to do

Unless you are willing to spend several months (or years) on this pursuit I would recommend you to use something already available, like [ocropus](http://code.google.com/p/ocropus/) or [javaocr](http://www.roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can purchase a HWR SDK from Vision Objects that will considerably reduce your development effort.